# html makes a request before angularjs loads

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I put a http request in the html like this:

```
<img src="/api/profilepic/user/{{user.id}}">
```

But the request turns out to be:

```
Request URL:https://example.com/api/profilepic/user/%7B%7Buser.id%7D%7D
```

Eventually, it keeps sending request until angular and user.id are initialized. But my node server will get a bunch of errors until so. Does anyone know how to solve this?

I tried using ng-switch like the following, but it doesn't work either.

```
<div ng-switch="user.id != null">
  <div ng-switch-when="true">                                                                     
    <img src="/api/profilepic/user/{{user.id}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `ng-src` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using AngularJS handles in the `src` attribute, it should be replaced with `ng-src`:

```
<img ng-src="/api/profilepic/user/{{user.id}}">
```

The Angular docs are your friend: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc